# Screen Capture from app using D3D11 Force Exclusive Mode

Tags: unity-game-engine, directx-11

I'm developing an application that runs using the "Force D3D11 Exclusive Mode" on Unity3d, but when a build is generated in that way, I can not capture the screen.

I am using the PrintWindow function of C #
I retrieve the hWnd of the process

```
Process.GetProcessesByName ("ImersioVR360");
 using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage (bitmap)) {
  IntPtr hdc = g.GetHdc (); 
  bool result = PrintWindow ((IntPtr) observedProcess.MainWindowHandle, hdc, 0);
  g.ReleaseHdc ();
  g.Flush ();
 g.Dispose ();
}
```

Only works when the application is not in accelerated mode.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: If you're drawing to a D3D surface, I'm not sure that what you've drawn is then visible on the window's HDC. Have you tried saving the D3D surface to file directly?

Comment: Hello, already tried saving the image, the way it is implemented above returns me a black image.
This otherwise error "violation of memory access" because the application be running in exclusive mode
     Process [] procs = Process.GetProcessesByName ("ImersioVR360");
             IntPtr hWnd = IntPtr.Zero;
             hWnd = prc.MainWindowHandle;
           Device device = new Device (hWnd);
           Surface backbuffer device.GetBackBuffer = (0, 0); // Here error
  All sugentão is welcome

Comment: Well are u trying to make a screenshot? And are you on PC or Mobile?
If the answers are Yes and PC/MAC/LINUX i have the solution